# how can i schedule a code to run after a given time even after powering off the computer. I want a program to calculate an interest after 30 days i

Tags: java

i am trying to calculate the interest after a 30 day period even when i power down .When i return after 31 days it should be able to calculate the interest for the the 30 days of if i return after 62 days.

```
public void double (Double principle, int accountType, Date openingDate){

    Date today = new Date();
    long currentMilSecs = today.getTime();
    long openingMilSecs = openingDate.getTime();

    long duration =  currentMilSecs - openingMilSecs;

    long secondsInMilli = 1000;
    long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
    long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
    long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;
    long monthsInMilli = daysInMilli * 30;

    long elapsedMonths = duration /monthsInMilli;
    duration = duration % monthsInMilli;
    long elapsedDays = duration / daysInMilli;
    duration = duration % daysInMilli;

    Double amount = 0.0, interestRate;
    double time = (elapsedMonths / 12);
    if((elapsedDays % 30) == 0) {
        switch (accountType){
            case 1:{
                interestRate = 0.12;
                amount = principle * (1 + (interestRate * time));
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                interestRate = 0.05;
                amount = principle * (1 + (interestRate * time));
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                interestRate = 0.10;
                amount = principle * (1 + (interestRate * time));
                break;
            }
            default:{
                interestRate = 0.00;
                amount = principle * (1 + (interestRate * time));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: What if computer is not turned on for say 40 or 60 days? What  you will need is many things. 1) Put your program to startup to start it automatically when PC starts (if you do not want to start manually). 2) Persist the date and other variables on PC, when program starts/is running for reference. Then use the persisted data to read.

Comment: Schedule it in the cloud.

Comment: Not sure if I get your problem. Sounds pretty simple: Store the date in a text file (csv for example) when you try to shut down. Like @Optional said put programm on autostart and calculate the difference according to the file you created.

Comment: what i meant is that if the computer has not been powered on for about 40 or 60 days, at whatever time the program has been restarted , it can calculate the elapsed time from the day let me say the  account was opened ,and if a month has passed it calculates the interest. It should be able to calculate the interest for every month that elapses whether it was powered on or off.